# Xml Document Object returns null, but not always

Tags: java, xml, io, xml-parsing

I have been recently trying to read from a xml file. I believe I am parsing correctly but it returns null,however not always.I received the input that I want 1 out of 100 executions, with no drastic changes on code.This is the code that receives the file path of xml file(also file in code)

```
public Document getXmlDoc(String filePath) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = dBuilder.parse(new File(filePath));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeValue());//null
        System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(1));//null
        System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getLastChild().getAttributes().getNamedItem("id"));//not null and correct
        System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("entry").item(1));//null
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();//pipe these
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return doc;
}
```

Also I call my method here and turn my node to string

```
  NodeList nList = getXmlDoc(newFilePath).getElementsByTagName("entry");
System.out.println(nodeToString(nList.item(i)));
```

Where nList is a node list and nodeToString method is like this:

```
private String nodeToString(Node node){
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try{
        Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,"yes");
        t.transform(new DOMSource(node),new StreamResult(sw));
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than one item? Item 1 is the second entry in the list.

Comment: I do have more than 1 , but even the first one is returning null. I have 7492 entries and successful print returns id="2018-7491"

Comment: getNodeValue());//null is correct on an element type node it seems. Also, whitespaces tend to be converted to null nodes sometimes. Is the number of nodes match the expected number of items?

Comment: I can't thank you enough, apparently whitespaces were null nodes, and I got what I want using odd indexes. Thanks!